# An invalid form control with name='name' is not focusable

Tags: javascript, html, form

Столкнулся с проблемой, связанной с проверкой полей формы.

Первая форма работает стабильно, а все последующие выдают ошибку в браузере

> An invalid form control with name='name' is not focusable.

Атрибут  **novalidate** не решил эту проблему

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="phorma1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <div class="pext"><h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Оставить заявку</h2></div>
          
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="
    text-align: left;
">
   <div class="main">

       
  <form id="application" action=" application.php" method="POST" name=" application " novalidate>
   <input name="name" id="applicationName" maxlength="20" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" required />
   <input name="email" type="email" id="applicationEmail" maxlength="20" placeholder="Введите ваш E-mail" required/>
   <input name="telephone" type="Tel" id="applicationTelephone" maxlength="20" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон" required />
   <button class="applicationButton" type="submit" form="application"> Отправить заявку </button>
  </form>
 </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Приведите код. input не заблокирован случайно?

Comment: Уберите required с hidden инпута и добавьте в вопрос [mcve]

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос